# Excluding rows containting consecutive zeros from data frame

Tags: r

I would like to exclude rows with at least 2 consecutive zeros from my data frame. Example:

```
subj    stimulus    var1   var2   var3   var4   
 1         A         25     30     15     36
 1         B          0      0     10      0
 1         C         12      0     20     23
```

I would like to exclude the trial for stimulus B containing two zeros, but keep the values for C containing only one. 
So far I have tried:

```
has3Zeros <- function(x) {
  x <- x[!is.na(x)] == 0 
  if (length(x) < 3) {
    FALSE 
  }
}
df[,!sapply(df, has3Zeros), drop=F]
```

but it tells me it is an invalid argument type. Is there an "easy" way to accomplish excluding rows with consecutive zeros?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Even though I scanned the web beforehand, I now used the right keywords and found the same question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797216/r-count-number-of-zeros-per-row-and-remove-every-row-more-than-5-zeros

In my case the answer would be: `df[rowSums(df==0)<=2,]`

Comment: that doesn't take account of whether they are `consecutive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are looking for any consecutive zeros in each row and want to exclude that row, one way would be to loop through the rows using `apply` and `MARGIN=1`.  Check whether there are `any` of the adjacent elements are equal and are zero, do the negation and subset the rows.

```
df1[!apply(df1[-(1:2)], 1, FUN = function(x) any((c(FALSE, x[-1]==x[-length(x)])) & !x)),]
#  subj stimulus var1 var2 var3 var4
#1    1        A   25   30   15   36
#3    1        C   12    0   20   23
```

---

Or if we need consecutive zero length to be 'n', then `rle` can be applied to each row, check whether the `lengths` for 'values' that are 0 is 'n', negate and subset the rows.

```
df1[!apply(df1[-(1:2)], 1, FUN = function(x) any(with(rle(x==0), lengths[values])==2)),]
#  subj stimulus var1 var2 var3 var4
#1    1        A   25   30   15   36
#3    1        C   12    0   20   23
```